# IQueryable Result set not getting correct data

Tags: c#, .net

I have an object `Student`, which has a navigation property to `Class`:

```
public class Student
{
   public virtual List<Class> Classes {get; set;}
}

public class Class
{
   public byte? Code {get; set;}
}
```

I have a `StudentVM` which has the `Code` in it for the class.

```
public class StudentVM
{
       public virtual List<Class> Classes {get; set;}
       public byte>? Code {get; set;}
}
```

In my StudentVM, my Code is not getting assigned properly.

```
public IQueryable<StudentVM> GetStudents()
{
     IQueryable<StudentVM> query = dbSet
                    .AsNoTracking()
                    .Include(x => x.Classes);

     var students = query.Select(x => new StudentVM 
                    {
                        Classes = x.Classes
                    });

     foreach (var s in students)
     {
        if (s.Classes.Any())
        {
           s.Code = s.Classes.FirstOrDefault().Code;
        }
     }

     return students;
}
```

The goal here is to check if the list of classes has anything in it, and if so, get the Code property from the first one in the list and map it to the StudentVM.Code property. However, when I inspect the return student list ResultsView, the studentVM.Code is null when it should have data. I'm new to IQueryable and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: I don't believe `Code` property of a `StudentVM` instance is `null` as that property is not nullable. It can be 0 (zero), but not `null`. Are you sure you're looking at the right code?

Comment: updated. I checked the code and Code is a nullable byte? But when I inspect s.Classes.FirstOrDefault().Code ...there is data in the code property, it's just not getting saved to s.Code.

Comment: Well, if `Class.Code` is nullable, it's expected to be null in some cases, right? So, even if `s.Classes.Any()` returns true, it doesn't guarantee that `s.Classes.First().Code` isn't null. Maybe you should consider `s.Classes.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Code != null)` instead? Then, you can get rid of the `Any()` check.